# Will DHS eventually stop wire transfers to/from Mt Gox?

Tags: mtgox, wire-transfers

This past week the US Dept of Homeland Security stopped all Dwolla transfers to/from Mt Gox.  Do wire transfers to/from Mt Gox still work?  Will the US DHS eventually shut down wire transfers to/from Mt Gox?

Comment: This question is far too speculative to be answered by our Q&A format...

Comment: Wire transfers still work fine.  Mine are taking about 5 days on average.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at beta bitinstant at https://new.bitinstant.com/ No longer option for cash to mtgox.  Could be possible indicator.